# Retrofit 2 @FormUrlEncoded with null fields

Tags: java, android, gson, retrofit2

I'm sending this:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@PUT("Devices/{id}")
Call<Device> updateDeviceSync(
        @Path("id") String id,
        @Field("fieldName1") Integer fieldName1,
        @Field("fieldName2") String fieldName2,
        @Field("fieldName3") String fieldName3);
```

I'm calling it with:

```
apiService.updateDeviceSync(deviceId, 0, null, timestamp)
```

But its only sending `fieldName1` and `fieldName3`

I already have `serializeNulls()` on my gsonbuilder so it should include nulls in there but logcat shows that its not including `fieldName2`

I need to update fieldName2 to null in retrofit2

Comment: Did you add in your retrofit builder addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create()))

Comment: @BrunoCaceiro yup I already have that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally made it work, Here are the changes I made:

Updated my api to:

```
@PUT("Devices/{id}")
Call<Device> updateDeviceCurfewSync(             
    @Path("id") String id,
    @Body HashMap<String, Object> data);
```

Then called:

```
HashMap<String, Object> deviceSyncMap = new HashMap<>();
deviceSyncMap.put("fieldName1", 0);
deviceSyncMap.put("fieldName2", null);
deviceSyncMap.put("fieldName3", timestamp);

apiService.updateDeviceCurfewSync(deviceId, deviceSyncMap)
```

Comment: Great fix, I was looking everywhere to see if I can pass null parameters in the request body, passing hash map solved it! Thanks.